# How to create a host application to receive data and send a response back

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am new to programming and i have given a project  which i have no idea how will to it.

I have to write a host application.The following is the requirement:

> Develop CXML webservice host for testing CXML posts from xyz.net .
>
> The application should read the stream of  data,validate against the dtd. store it in  to the corresponding tables and send a response back to the client.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 0):

This should help you for example. create a console application, and set the startup object to SelfHost. Run the application and you wcf service should be available at the URL stated into the code : http://localhost:1234/hello"

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IIndexer
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Test();

}

public class Indexer : IIndexer
{
    public bool Test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}


    class SelfHost
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/hello");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Indexer), baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press Q and <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();


                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```